# How can I return only selected fields on C# Web API

Tags: c#, rest

I have this serviceLayer Method that is used by my Web API proyect to return data to clients:

```
public IEnumerable<Contactos_view> ListarVistaNew(int activos, string filtro, int idSector, int idClient, string ordenar, int registroInic, int registros)
        {
            using (var myCon = new AdoNetContext(new AppConfigConnectionFactory(EmpresaId)))
            {
                using (var rep = base_getRep(myCon))
                {
                    return rep.Listar(activos, filtro, idSector, idClient, ordenar, registroInic, registros);
                }
            }
        }
```

Now the question is: How can I return only desired property of class Contactos_view? This class contains 20 properties, and my Idea is to add a parameter of type `string[] Fields` so client can select only the desired propeties. 
Is it possible? what would be the returned type of `ListarVistaNew` in that case?

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you create a DTO that is specific to the things you want to return, and then map the superset to the subset? Then it's clear to people coming behind you what your code is doing.

Comment: Thank you. In this case I will have to create a separated class for every posible combination of propertys that the client can request. One client can need property 1 and 2, other property 2 and 3 and a third property 1 and 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dynamically create and populate expando objects.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ClientSelectsProperties
{
    public class OriginalType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        // this simulates your original query result - it has all properties
        private static List<OriginalType> queryResult = new List<OriginalType> {
            new OriginalType { Id = 1, Name = "one", Description = "one description" },
            new OriginalType { Id = 2, Name = "two", Description = "two description" }
        };

        // "hardcoded" property value readers, go crazy here and construct them dynamically if you want (reflection, code generation...)
        private static Dictionary<string, Func<OriginalType, object>> propertyReaders = new Dictionary<string, Func<OriginalType, object>> {
            { "Id", t => t.Id },
            { "Name", t => t.Name },
            { "Description", t => t.Description }
        };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // your client only wants Id and Name
            var result = GetWhatClientWants(new List<string> { "Id", "Name" });
        }

        private static List<dynamic> GetWhatClientWants(List<string> propertyNames)
        {
            // make sure your queryResult is in-memory collection here. Body of this select cannot be executed in the database
            return queryResult.Select(t =>
            {
                var expando = new ExpandoObject();
                var expandoDict = expando as IDictionary<string, object>;

                foreach (var propertyName in propertyNames)
                {
                    expandoDict.Add(propertyName, propertyReaders[propertyName](t));
                }

                return (dynamic)expando;
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see your point. It sounds pretty complex, but i will look into it. Another option i'm considering let my API like it is and create an intermediate layer on server side between the API and the WEB Client, that get the entire JSON and return to client only desired fields. Great!